# how do I create a ctags file recursively?

Tags: vim, ctags, taglist

I would like to create a tags file using `ctags` for a complete source tree. Now I generally would run `ctags *.c` but the problem is in the top directory, there's no source files. 
Also, I'd like it to pick up `*.c`,`*.h`,`*.cpp` & `*.hpp` files, how can I do this?

Comment: `ctags --recurse` or `ctags -R` should work.  Which version of ctags are you using?

Comment: @WilliamPursell `Ctags 5.9~svn20110310` from the Ubuntu repo and if you add your comment as an answer, I'll accept it as such!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `ctags --recurse` or `ctags -R` to recursively descend into a directory tree.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, when I tried this, there was a `ctags` installed, but it did not support `--recurse`.  I did `sudo apt-get install ctags` and then this worked fine.

Comment: be aware that emacs-ctags does not have a `--recurse`, verbose (`-v`) will should the vendor or check the help output to see if it has recurse

Comment: -R is ignore regex in ctags (GNU Emacs 27.2)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to generate tags for c/c++/javascript/java/python files present in your git repo (respecting .gitignore) :

```
git ls-files | ctags --links=no --languages=c,c++,javascript,java,python -L-
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any source in the root directory, the best way to filter is with the `--languages` option. Here's one I used for a mixed-language project, where I only wanted tags for the Tcl files.

```
ctags -R --languages=Tcl .
```

Note, if you need support for multiple languages, you can add them with ,

To see the list of languages, use `--list-languages`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ctags -R` or `stags --recurse`, as others have suggested.

However, as mentioned by user cxw, this doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.

Here's what I found.  The default install has:

```
# ctags --version
ctags (GNU Emacs 25.2)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is distributed under the terms in ETAGS.README
```

Then, after `sudo apt-get install ctags`, I get:

```
# ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex
```

And now the recurse option works.